# How to filter out msteam groups from groups graph api response?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

The `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups` endpoint returns all Groups, including Groups created for Microsoft Teams. I could not see any attribute related to Microsoft Teams from the response. So was looking for a way to identify if a Group is Microsoft Teams.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to do this yet. Teams and the Graph team will deliver this sometime this year, but we don't have a date yet. A LOT of people need this though.

Specifically, there will be an attribute for a group that clearly identifies the services associated with each (not just Teams, but also Planner and Power BI, and of course Exchange and SharePoint), but also the ability to query groups with specific attributes as you describe.